# Meaning of Symbols/Icons on Amgen-ToC Stage Maps

Tags: maps, racing

Can someone help parse the symbols on the stage maps for Amgen-ToC?

There does not seem to be a legend on any of the maps.  e.g. http://cdn.amgentourofcalifornia.com/uploads/images/2017stages/AmgenTOC17_Stage-02_012617.pdf
[image]

Some seem pretty obvious:

- Blue circle with right-pointing white triangle  =  Stage Start
- Red circle with 1 to 5 or "HC" : Climbs with difficulty-category
- Red circle with checkered square : Stage finish

One I'm less certain of:

- Blue circle with knife/fork : Safe for riders to take food here (long flat straight stretch)???

Two I have no idea:

- Green circle with white "S" : ???  (maybe some sort of points/premium spot?)
- Blue circle with "Km 0" (about 10 km after the start) : ???

After lots of searching, I've found that last year's maps use the same symbols, but again without any legend.  I found another site on which someone asked a similar question about the Tour of Switzerland, but some of those symbols are different.

Can anyone help me out here?   Thanks!

Comment: Green "S" is probably the location of the Sprint Competition as they give a green jersey for Sprint winner / leader. Knife and fork for food, supplied by team. They seem to have forgotten to supply a key with the map.

Comment: KeithWM is right. "S" are sprint points. The feed zone where teams are allowed to hand up food bags to the riders is on San Antonio Rd. The first loops in Modesto are "neutralized" (that is, it's more like a parade), and the real beginning of the race starts right outside of town at marker 0.

Comment: @R.Chung why do you keep putting answers in comments?  There's nothing in your comment that stops it being an answer to the question.

Comment: I don't really need the points and I've been hoping that someone who does would use my comments to improve their answer, get voted up, and continue to participate. In this case, I was thinking that @KeithWM made the first correct comment so could write an answer and incorporate my comment.

Comment: Thanks @R.Chung and thanks for reminding me about neutralised parts, I now remember them from my own racing days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RED Circle with numbers 1-5 : Climbs with range of difficulty

RED Circle with numbers "HC" : Hors catégorie or Above Category

Blue Circle with knife/fork : Feed Zone where you grab your musette

Green Circle with white "S" : Sprint Zone

Blue Circle with "km 0" : Just means no break-away is allowed before this point. In essence "the race starts here"

Comment: Your last list contradicts the fourth line - suggest erasing the last line completely.

Comment: I thought he said white circle. I'm color blind.